# Set neighbor to specific value around mask inidices

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array called `mask` I would like to set the `n` neighboring cells around every zero also to zero.

The following code works but is obviously fairly slow because of the looping and because I am setting the same cells multiple times to zero. I was wondering whether one can come up with a more efficient version than this.

```
_, ind_x, ind_y = np.where(mask == 0)
xmax_total = mask.shape[1]
ymax_total = mask.shape[2]
n =3
for ix, iy in zip(ind_x, ind_y):
    xmin = max(ix-n, 0)
    xmax = min(ix+n+1, xmax_total)
    ymin = max(iy-n, 0)
    ymax = min(iy+n+1, ymax_total)
    mask[:, xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax] = 0
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. So I find it impossible to make a full answer, for example, what are those three dimensions in your mask? Anyway, the operation that you are looking for is [binary erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)). Scipy implements that as [`scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion). Probably with `structure=np.ones((n*2+1,)*2, 'b')`